# Keeping text inline

Tags: html, css

I have an image that is floated to the left and then some text to the right of the image. However the text is just long enough that one line of a paragraph goes below the image. How to I keep this text inline with the paragraph and keep it from wrapping around the picture?

Comment: is the text contained inside a div? and are they both floated? I suspect they aren't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to worry about knowing and setting any widths, you can do this by [establishing a new block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) for the text container.

i.e. For the markup:

```
<img src="image.jpg">
<p>Some text
```

all you need do is give the `<p>` element an overflow other than "visible". For example:

```
p { overflow:auto; }
```

Use a little bit of margin-right on the `<img>` to separate the text from the image.

Answer (score 2):

If your image is floated to the left, the trick is to have a `margin-left` of at least the `width` of the image for whatever element your text is contained in.

For example, if your HTML is something like:

```
<img src="image.jpg">
<p>Some text
```

And the width of your image is 160px, you have to give your paragraph a `margin-left` of at least 160px (it does look nicer if you give it `margin-left` that's slightly bigger than 160px).

That's all you need to do after you have floated the image, just set the `margin-left` on the paragraph following it. You don't even need to specify a width for the paragraph.

Demo http://dabblet.com/gist/2791183

Answer (score 1):

You need to the float the image element and the text element separately. I think you also need to specify width for both elements.

```
<img src"url()" style="float:left; width:100px;">
<div id="text" style="float:left; width:500px;">Words</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not place your text in another block element, then it will always wrap around that other floated element.  The way floats work is it takes an element out of the "document flow", [here's some more specific information on how floats work](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/).  The only way to get your text to not wrap is to also place it inside of a block element (like a `div` tag) and float that element with the floated image to the left.

Example:

```
<div style="overflow: auto;">
    <img src="hello.jpg" style="float: left; width: 200px;">
    <div style="float: left; width: 700px;">
        Hello!!!
    </div>
</div>
```

The first `overflow: auto` will declare a height for the container.  It's the same concept as adding `clear: both` in a div tag underneath the image and text div.  Remember to always clear your floats!  :)